# electron js vite error during start dev server and electron app: Error: Electron uninstall

Tags: javascript, electron, vite

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byoJK.png)
> electron js vite error during start dev server and electron app: Error: Electron uninstall

start electron app I Tried reinstalling a lot of things node js and pnpm, yarn but it doesn't work
everything worked fine before an ordinary electron didn't work anymore either

Comment: Did you find an answer for it. I have the same issue here